# como puedo hacer un SELECT * FROM WHILE con un Array PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array

tengo una consulta... yo tengo en una tabla llamada monedas un campo llamado Prefijo y en otra tabla llamada directorios tengo un campo donde guardo la palabra DEL es decir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que deseo es mostrar en un select-box es, primero que despliegue pais  y ciudad, y en otro select box despliegue las monedas disponibles, claro esto es un ejemplo ya que en realidad tengo un directorio de más de 3mil registros donde cada pais esta dividido por ciudad y cada ciudad esta dividida por distritos y cada distrito tiene ciertas agenicas.

entonces, la solucion para amarrar las tablas fue poner solo un campo donde este esos prefijos ya que esto luego se usara en otra tabla de tarifas y tiene campos como rango inicial y rango final y cada pais, ciudad, etc. tiene distintas tarifas. para evitar crear otra tabla donde esté registrado cada agencia tiene distintas tarifas me daría un resultado inmenso y no sería nada factible aplicar esto ya que luego estaría propenso a cambios y darle mantenimiento a esta tabla sería imposible por el numero colosal de registros es por ello que trato de hacer en un selec *from un array asosiativo en PHP

este es el código:

```
    <?php 
        $vMonedas_Habilitadas=$_POST['Prefijo'];

        //--->Prefijo es de la tabla directorio = DEL

        $Arreglo = str_split($vMonedas_Habilitadas);

        //segun lo que lei en el manual de php la funcion str_split me devuelve una cadena en arreglo entonces aqui convierto el string DEL en array [D,E,L]

        //ya teniendo el array [D,E,L] ahora quiero filtrar que monedas estan disponibles al seleccionar un registro
        $result = "SELECT * FROM tabla_moneda WHERE Prefijo IN (".implode(",",$Arreglo).")";


    $resultadoMD = $mysqli->query($result);

    $html= "<option value='0' selected >Moneda no seleccionada</option>";

    while($row = $resultadoMD->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $html.= "<option value='".$row['vIndicador']."'>".$row['vNombre_Moneda']."</option>";
        }

        echo $html;

     ?>
```

he tratado de filtrar pero aun no tengo exito en la ejecucion del codigo el error podria ser en la consulta SQL he utilizado el comando implode pero mi codigo no ejecuta

alguna manera de hacer un SELECT*FROM con un array asosiativo ?

estuve buscando temas relacionados pero no especificamente a lo que trato de hacer, de antemano doy gracias a las recomendacion o soluciones.

Comment: Carlos, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Leí tu pregunta, pero no entendí del todo lo que quieres hacer. No me parece que sea tan difícil si diseñas bien tus tablas. En MySQL existen funciones de agrupación, por ejemplo `GROUP_CONCAT`, la cual, combinada con  `GROUP BY` te traerá los diferentes resultados con un separador, uniendo las tablas relacionadas. Creo que es una mejor opción, de acuerdo a lo que he podido entender en lo que explicas. El problema, creo yo, está en tu modelo de datos, no es del todo correcto y por eso te está dando problemas ahora para obtener este resultado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida :)  editaré la pregunta para hacerla más entendible

Comment: creo entender tu pregunta y al parecer lo que tu deseas es hacer select dinámicos anidados los cuales al seleccionar un prefijo te digan solo aquellos paises y ciudades con ese mismo prefijo o viceversa es correcto? si ese fuera el caso comentalo y te podria ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no estas imprimiendo correctamente los campos de tu base de datos. Tratas de imprimir los campos **vIndicador** y **vNombre_Moneda** cuando son **n** y **NombreMoneda**.

Intenta cambiando:

```
$html.= "<option value='".$row['vIndicador']."'>".$row['vNombre_Moneda']."</option>";
```

Por:

```
$html.= "<option value='".$row['n']."'>".$row['NombreMoneda']."</option>";
```

Comment: ups, me olvide de cambiar esas variables, lo que pasa es que el codigo lo he resubido y cambiado de variables, en realidad si estan estas variables declaradas en el select, editare la pregunta corrigiendo los errores de redaccion que he hecho para que sea mas entendible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu requerimiento, podrías hacer la query de la siguiente forma (sin necesidad de utilizar la función `str_split()`):

En este caso 'DEL' sería el valor que se encuentra en la variable $vMonedas_Habilitadas (que lo obtiene de `$_POST['Prefijo']`, en la primer query está harcodeado); la query solo retornará la monedas cuyo Prefijo (letra) se encuentre presente en dicha viriable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla_moneda 
WHERE 'DEL' like concat('%', Prefijo, '%');
```

Con php deberías usar `Prepared Statements` para prevenir ataques del tipo `SQL inyección`, y lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_moneda WHERE ? like concat('%', Prefijo, '%')");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vMonedas_Habilitadas);
$stmt->execute();
$resultadoMD = $stmt->get_result();

?>
```